# Migrating DbConnectionFactory from .net to.net core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm trying to migrate a small .net framework project to .net core one. But I've spent a couple of hours searching how to adopt the code below to .net core 2.0. But I was unlucky, because it seems that System.Data.Common functionality was cut for some reason. So, I've 2 problems here:

1. How to get provider name from connection string? Do we have ConnectionStringSettings for .net core 2.0
2. How can we get a factory base only on provider name string?
   Any other thought how to perform loosely coupled db connection factory

   ```
   public class ConnectionFactory
   {
       protected readonly DbProviderFactory Factory;

       protected readonly string ConnectionString;

       public ConnectionFactory(string connectionStringName)
       {
           var settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName];
           this.Factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(settings.ProviderName);
           this.ConnectionString = settings.ConnectionString;
       }

       public DbConnection Connection
       {
           get
           {
               var con = Factory.CreateConnection();
               con.ConnectionString = this.ConnectionString;
               return con;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Did you try searching for `System.Data.Common` in NuGet? Version 4.3.0 should work for .NET Core 2

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto, version 4.3.0 (the latest) is installed to my project but I still can't reference DbProviderFactories

Comment: What's the error message? Because it does exist: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Data.Common/src/System/Data/Common/DbProviderFactory.cs

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto, unfortunately it doesn't. I'm looking for DbProviderFactories and the reference kindly provided by you is to DbProviderFactory. This is the abstract class and I need somehow to get its instance. Earlier I did it this way DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(settings.ProviderName);

Comment: Sorry, my bad, but it still exists: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Data.Common/src/System/Data/Common/DbProviderFactories.cs

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto, yes, now I see it does. But I can't reference to it. VS simply warn me that this name doesn't exist. My target framework is .net core 2.0 and project type is .net core class library. Any thoughts? ((

Comment: Try either clean/rebuild or updating to the latest .NET Core version (2.1.4) and updating all packages. You may have a version previous to the one that contains that class

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto dotnet --version shows me 2.1.4. I did clean and rebuild solution. Still the same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164096/discussion-between-managerger-and-camilo-terevinto).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DbProviderFactories will be available in .net core 2.1 (2Q 2018).